# Error with creating a form that gives a result depending on numeric values of radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to coding and wanted to start off simple. I am working on creating a form where the user makes selections using radio buttons and it gives a result based on numeric values of the selections. All code is on one page and I want to keep to just using html and javascript. Any help would be appreciated. When I run the code the "totalSev" is defaulting to "S4" no matter what the value of "totalValue" is.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="customerImpact">
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<input type="radio" name="impact" value="5"/> 
<label for="impact1">Answer 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="impact" value="4"/>
<label for="impact2">Answer 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="impact" value="3"/>
<label for="impact3">Answer 3</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="impact" value="2"/>
<label for="impact4">Answer 4</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="impact" value="1"/>
<label for="impact5">Answer 5</label>
</div>
<div id="customerRanking">
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<input type="radio" name="ranking" value="4"/>
<label for="rankingl">Answer 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="ranking" value="3"/>
<label for="ranking2">Answer 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="ranking" value="3"/>
<label for="ranking3">Answer 3</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="ranking" value="2"/>
<label for="ranking4">Answer 4</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="ranking" value="1"/>
<label for="ranking4">Answer 5</label><br>
</div>
<div id="endUsersAffected">
<h3>Question 3</h3>
<input type="radio" name="endusers" value="3"/>
<label for="endusers1">Answer 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="endusers" value="2"/>
<label for="endusers2">Answer 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="endusers" value="1"/>
<label for="endusers3">Answer 3</label><br>
</div>
<div id="customerUrgency">
<h3>Question 4</h3>
<input type="radio" name="urgency" value="3"/>
<label for="urgency1">Answer 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="urgency" value="2"/>
<label for="urgency2">Answer 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="urgency" value="1"/>
<label for="urgency3">Answer 3</label><br>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="getValue()">Calculate</button>
<p id="message"></p>
<b><p id="severity"></p></b>
```

javascript:

```
var totalValue = "";
var totalSev = "";
var totalValueNum = "";
function impactNum() {
var impact = document.getElementsByName('impact');
var impactBracket;
var impactNumerical;

for (var i = 0; i < impact.length; i++) {
    if (impact[i].checked) {
        impactBracket = impact[i].value;
    }
}

if (impactBracket == "5") {
    impactNumerical = 5;
} else if (impactBracket == "4") {
    impactNumerical = 4;
} else if (impactBracket == "3") {
    impactNumerical = 3;
} else if (impactBracket == "2") {
    impactNumerical = 2;
} else if (impactBracket == "1") {
    impactNumerical = 1;
} else {
    impactNumerical = 0;
}
return impactNumerical;
}

function rankingNum() {
var ranking = document.getElementsByName('ranking');
var rankingValue;
var rankingNumerical;
for (var i = 0; i < ranking.length; i++) {
    if (ranking[i].checked) {
        rankingValue = ranking[i].value;
    }
}
if (rankingValue == "4") {
    rankingNumerical = 4;
} else if (rankingValue == "3") {
    rankingNumerical = 3;
} else if (rankingValue == "3") {
    rankingNumerical = 3;
} else if (rankingValue == "2") {
    rankingNumerical = 2;
} else if (rankingValue == "1") {
    rankingNumerical = 1;
} else {
    rankingNumerical = 0;
}
return rankingNumerical;

}

function endusersNum() {
var endusers = document.getElementsByName('endusers');
var enduserAnswer;
var enduserNumerical;

for (var i = 0; i < endusers.length; i++) {
    if (endusers[i].checked) {
        enduserAnswer = endusers[i].value;

    }
}
if (enduserAnswer == "3") {
    enduserNumerical = 3;
} else if (enduserAnswer == "2") {
    enduserNumerical = 2;
} else if (enduserAnswer == "1") {
    enduserNumerical = 1;
} else {
    enduserNumerical = 0;
}

return enduserNumerical;

}


function urgencyNum() {
var urgency = document.getElementsByName('urgency');
var urgencyAnswer;
var urgencyNumerical;
for (var i = 0; i < urgency.length; i++) {
    if (urgency[i].checked) {
        urgencyAnswer = urgency[i].value;
    }
}

if (urgencyAnswer == "3") {
    urgencyNumerical = 3;
} else if (urgencyAnswer == "2") {
    urgencyNumerical = 2;
} else if (urgencyAnswer == "1") {
    urgencyNumerical = 1;
} else {
    urgencyNumerical = 0;
}

return urgencyNumerical;

}

function getValue() {

var a = impactNum();
var b = rankingNum();
var c = endusersNum();
var d = urgencyNum();


totalValue = a + b + c + d;

console.log("Impact: " + impactNum());
console.log("Ranking: " + rankingNum());
console.log("End Users: " + endusersNum());
console.log("Urgency: " + urgencyNum());
console.log("Total: " + totalValue);


console.log(typeof totalValue);

document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Points: " + totalValue;
document.getElementById('severity').innerHTML = "Severity: " + totalSev;

}

if (totalValue == 15) {
totalSev = "S1";
} else if (totalValue == 14) {
totalSev = "S1";
} else if (totalValue == 13) {
totalSev = "S1";
} else if (totalValue == 12) {
totalSev = "S2"; 
} else if (totalValue == 11) {
totalSev = "S2";
} else if (totalValue == 10) {
totalSev = "S3";
} else if (totalValue == 9) {
totalSev = "S3";
} else {
totalSev = "S4"
}
```

Comment: Converting "3" to 3:    var num = Number(str)

Comment: According to what you put here you doing check of totalValue before it calculated - so it always going to last >> else { totalSev = "S4"

Comment: Indent your code.

Comment: @Nosyara I have moved the check of totalValue to the bottom of the javascript and it still defaults to "S4".

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('impact');
```

getElementsByName refers to HTML Tag names: DIV, INPUT, SPAN, etc.

You want [document.querySelectAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectAll('input[name=impact]')
```

Additionally, the value of the input will always return a string.

Convert

```
impactBracket = impact[i].value;
```

To

```
// note the + coercing the string to a number
impactBracket = +impact[i].value;
```